# In R Shiny, how to eliminate the flashing of observeEvent conditionals when first invoking the App?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

In the below MWE code, the object `input2` is optionally called by the user by clicking the "Show" radio button for Input 2. Default setting is to hide `input2`. However, when first invoking the App, `input2` quickly flashes by before being hidden by the `observeEvent`.

This flashing is much more pronounced in the non-MWE version of the code.

There is a related post *[In R shiny, how to eliminate flashing of all conditional panels in sidebar when first invoking the App without using renderUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69162147/in-r-shiny-how-to-eliminate-flashing-of-all-conditional-panels-in-sidebar-when)* that addresses this issue for `conditionalPanel`. But here there is no `conditionalPanel`.

I do not want to use `renderUI` to resolve this issue!! As `renderUI` has drawbacks I don't want to re-introduce.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

f <- function(action,i){as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(action,i),label=NULL))}
actions       <- c("show", "reset")
tbl           <- t(outer(actions, c(1,2), FUN = Vectorize(f)))
colnames(tbl) <- c("Show", "Reset")
rownames(tbl) <- c("Input 2", "Input 3")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "td .checkbox {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
       td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;}"
    ))
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("input1", "Input 1:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
      h5(strong("Add inputs:")),
      tableOutput("checkboxes"),
      numericInput("input2", "Input 2:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )    
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["checkboxes"]] <- 
    renderTable({tbl}, 
                rownames = TRUE, align = "c",
                sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
    )

  observeEvent(input[["show1"]], {
    if(input[["show1"]] %% 2 == 1){shinyjs::show(id = "input2")} else
      {shinyjs::hide(id = "input2")}
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some time in the event loop until `observerEvent` is called the first time.
By default, it will be displayed at the very beginning.
This results into a flash.
Just hide `input2` at the very beginning of the `server` function:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Avoid flashing
  shinyjs::hide(id = "input2")
  
  output[["checkboxes"]] <-
    renderTable(
      {
        tbl
      },
      rownames = TRUE,
      align = "c",
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
    )

  observeEvent(input[["show1"]], {
    if (input[["show1"]] %% 2 == 1) {
      shinyjs::show(id = "input2")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide(id = "input2")
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `hidden`

```
hidden(numericInput("input2", "Input 2:", 10, min = 1, max = 100))
```

---

and `toggle`:

```
  observeEvent(input[["show1"]], {
    toggle("input2")
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```