# How to avoid initial loading with flickering of all conditionalPanels in sidebarMenu while Shiny Application loads?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

In the code below, I am creating a dynamic `sidebarMenu` based on the selected tab. During the initial load of this application, the `sidebarMenu` for both tabs is rendered even though only `tab 1` is selected. In my original application, this is causing a delay in loading time as I have a lot of controls on each tab.

While application loads, is there a way to load only the sidebar controls of the active tab instead of loading sidebar controls of both the tabs?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "menu_sidebar",
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 1'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "t1", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(30:40))),
      print("Hello Tab 1")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 2'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "t2", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(40:50))),
      print("Hello Tab 2")
    )
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "main_tab",
      selected = "tab 1",
      tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel(title = "tab 2", "Tab content 2")
    )
  )
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `insertUI` along with an `observeEvent` which is called only `once` to achive this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "menu_sidebar",
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 1'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "t1", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(30:40))),
      div("Hello Tab 1")
    ))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "main_tab",
      selected = "tab 1",
      tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel(title = "tab 2", "Tab content 2")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$main_tab == 'tab 2', {
      insertUI(
        selector = "#menu_sidebar",
        where = "afterEnd",
        ui = conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 2'",
          selectizeInput(inputId = "t2", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(40:50))),
          div("Hello Tab 2")
        ),
        immediate = TRUE,
        session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
      )
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to move ```observeEvent```/ ```insertUI ``` into a separate function or file so that the ```server``` function does not grow out of proportion?

Comment: Sure you can e.g. wrap the code in a function and put it in a separate *.R-file in the R/ directory (subdir of your app) so they are sourced automatically. See [this related article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/app-formats.html) or you put them somewhere else and use `source` yourself in the server function.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer by ismirsehregal helped me solve this problem more elegantly.
The idea is taken from a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69250331/11939840).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  collapsed = FALSE,
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "menu_sidebar",
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 1'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "t1", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(30:40))),
      print("Hello Tab 1"),
      style = "display: none;"
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.main_tab == 'tab 2'",
      selectizeInput(inputId = "t2", label = "Select by:", choices = c(as.character(40:50))),
      print("Hello Tab 2"),
      style = "display: none;"
    )
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "main_tab",
      selected = "tab 1",
      tabPanel(title = "tab 1", "Tab content 1"),
      tabPanel(title = "tab 2", "Tab content 2")
    )
  )
)


shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "tabBoxes"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
  }
)
```